# How to determinate whether superset will be open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M = (X, d)$ and A is closed subset of X, i.e. $A \subseteq X$. $A$ is told to be closed, iff it's complement $X\setminus A$ is open in $M$.

But how can we determine, whether superset is open or closed in case, that we have just general superset $X$? What if our superset is $\mathbb{R}^n$?

If we are doing complement $X\setminus A$ will this empty area in $X$ have bounds or not?

Comment: You can’t tell whether an arbitrary superset of $A$ is closed without further information. However, $\Bbb R^n$ is certainly closed, since its complement, $\varnothing$, is open.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but if we have, let's say $\mathbb{R}^2$ and in it we have a closed ball $B$, shouldn't be $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ open? Is this a case, when set is both open and closed?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb R^2\setminus B$ will then be open; it is not a superset of $B$, however.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity I recommend thinking about this problem in terms of subspace topologies. Though, you need information about the superset beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I may be interpreting your question wrong but it seems to me you are asking if $X$ is closed or open in the metric space $M=(X, d)$. And the answer to that is: yes. The entire metric space is always closed AND open within itself.

This can be confusing. We know $(0, 1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but it is true that $(0, 1)$ is also closed when the metric space in consideration is itself.

Why? Look at the (one) definition of closed sets. It says a set is closed when very convergent sequence in it converges to a point within it. Let our metric space be $(0, 1)$ and $x_n$ be a convergent sequence in it. This means it converges to a point in the metric space (because there are no points "outside" it). The metric space also happens to be the set in consideration, and so the set itself is closed because the point of convergence lies in it.

But, wait a minute, what about a sequence like $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$? The answer is that this sequence actually is NOT convergent in our metric space. Because the very definition of convergence requires the point of convergence to lie within $(0, 1)$  and there is no point in it where this convergence applies.

Just to be clear, I assumed the regular distance metric of $\mathbb{R}$ in the above example but that is purely for illustrative purposes. This holds for any distance metric.